# KeyListener won't listen on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

It's a very simple program, but for some reason when I debug it and set breakpoints at the `keyPressed`, `keyReleased` and `keyTyped` method, the program never stops there.

```
    mainKeyListener = new KeyListener() {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Here I add it to a `JPanel`, which is the exact size of the frame and the only object on it:

```
    JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    backgroundPanel.setBounds(0,0, 400, 500);
    backgroundPanel.addKeyListener(mainKeyListener);
    backgroundPanel.setFocusable(true);
    getContentPane().add(backgroundPanel);
```

Comment: Are you sure you adds key listener ***after*** you have created it?

Comment: @CuppleKay, did you tried this: `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled()`

Comment: I have to try a couple of things now but the problem seems to be that I created the backgroundPanel in a method, which i called before I created the KeyListener just like @Kao said.

Comment: @robzillaDev I'm amazed how you can repeat others and think you are constructive.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is laying in focused element. I think that your panel lost the focus.

**Note:** 
To fire keyboard events, a component must have the keyboard focus. It can be solved in many ways for your example you can use  *KeyboardFocusManager*  for example like this:

```
KeyboardFocusManager focusManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        focusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                if(focusManager.getFocusOwner()!=backgroundPanel){
                                focusManager.redispatchEvent(backgroundPanel,e);
                                return true;}
                else return false;
            }
        });
```

Also try to use  Key Bindings    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi this should work for you.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame
{


private JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel();

public Gui() throws HeadlessException
{
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    setPanelProps();
    backgroundPanel.addKeyListener(createListener());
    this.add(backgroundPanel);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(400,500));
}

public void setPanelProps(){
    backgroundPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 500);
    backgroundPanel.setSize(new Dimension(400,500));
    backgroundPanel.setFocusable(true);
    backgroundPanel.setBackground(new Color(50,60,70));
}


public KeyListener createListener(){
    return new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("KEY TYPED");
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("KEY PRESSED");
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("KEY RELEASED");
        }

    };

}
}


public class GuiRun
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Gui gui = new Gui();

}
}
```

Comment: `You where probably adding the listener to the panel after it was added to the JFrame` - that doesn't matter. You can add the KeyListener to the panel at any time you want.